# Reassign the Right button functionality of touchpad

Tags: 12.04, touchpad, hp-pavilion, button

My notebook has a touchpad with two buttons.

[image]

The touchpad works pretty well and I use it for vertical/horizontal scroll, two fingers scrolling etc. The Left button acts like the left button of a mouse. The Right button too, when clicked it makes appear the classic contextual menu (create new folder, move to trash etc...).

**The problem is that Right button doesn't work anymore for mechanical reasons, so pressing it has no effect.**

To recover the missing functionality, I'd like that pressing CTRL + Left button I get the same thing of pressing the Right button alone. Other combinations (CTRL + SHIFT + Left button) are also acceptable.

Any way to do that?

Comment: Not sure whether you can achieve this using Left button & Ctrl combination. But the workaround is to use "Shift+F10" or install xdotool and stimulate the behavior by using command `xdotool click 3` and assign it to some key combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer (along with @devav2 comment) helped a lot: https://askubuntu.com/a/97784/18140

In my case the content of `$HOME/.xbindkeysrc` is:

```
"xdotool click --clearmodifiers 3"
  Control + b:1 + Release
```

It does exactly what I was looking for and works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `easystroke`, which is a gesture recognition application.

You can specify a particular gesture and bind it to an action.

[image: Easystroke Ubuntu]