# Emulate with keyboard holding down left mouse button

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, button

I have an external keyboard with a touchpad, like [this](http://www.notebooksbilliger.de/rapoo+kabellose+touchpad+tastatur+e2800p+242993/?nbb=pla.google_&wt_cc2=912-0001_Hardware_242993&gclid=CIrImMu7o8wCFbQV0wodYoMCDA). The touchpad had no physical buttons but it only emulates left click with a one finger tap and right click with a three finger tap.

With this setting it's not possible to drag and drop files or to make mouse gestures and so on, but if I could emulate somehow holding down the left mouse button using some key(s) on the keyboard, I'd solve the problem.

I already tried the universal access utility that lets you use the numeric keypad to emulate the mouse (it's an older model in which the touchpad can be converted to a numeric keypad with a swipe on the bottom, wtf :) ), but I did not manage to click and move at the same time, can you?

I also tried keynav, but did not like it much and couldn't do anything with it.

Hopefully it's a solvable problem!

Comment: If you double-click what you want to drag, but hold down on the second tap, you should be able to drag it.

Comment: thanks, I didn't know, it works! the only issue is that I have a big monitor and I cannot drag for long distances, because the touchpad is not large enough. and if I want to copy a file into a folder it just goes back to were it was if I drop it before I'm hovering onto the folder :(

Comment: It might be a duplicate of this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/97748/how-do-i-bind-right-click-to-a-keyboard-shortcut

Comment: It's for right-click, but it's the same idea.